# Значение словаря переходят не к тому ключу

Tags: python-3.x, регулярные-выражения

Помогите, пожалуйста! Пишу здесь, так как всю голову сломал и не могу понять "почему?" происходит:
Есть выполнение заданий на основе подключения библиотек fitz и re:
1. Python получает pdf-файл, читает его и выводит в значения;
2. Очищает от лишних символов и заносит в словарь - это для избежания обрывка текста;
3. В словаре находит значение и присваивает своё новое имя для дальнейшей работы. И тут есть проблема одна.

Все строки выполняет на отлично, но одну строку всегда отправляет в предыдущую

```
for i in range(text_blocks.count('\n')):
    a = text_blocks.index('\n')
    print('text blocks index:', str(a))
    card_var = text_blocks[b:a]
    card_var_new = ''.join(card_var)
    b = a
    print('card_var_new:', '\n'+card_var_new, str(i))
    text_blocks.pop(a)
    if re.search(name1,card_var_new): 
        temp[i] = card_var_new
        print(temp[i])
        continue
    elif re.search(name2,card_var_new): 
        temp[i] = card_var_new
        print(temp[i])
    <..>
    else:
        if temp.get(i-1) != None: 
            temp[i-1] += ' '+card_var_new
        elif temp.get(i-2) != None: 
            temp[i-2] += ' '+card_var_new
        <..>
        elif temp.get(i-7) != None: 
            temp[i-7] += ' '+card_var_new

for key in temp.keys():
    print('i -', key, temp[key])
```

В итоге, получается, что считывает всё правильно, но почему-то на основе else отправляет в предыдущее имя:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И именно с этой строкой проблемы и не могу понять почему - текст переписывал, имена менял:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `elif re.search(re.escape(trade),card_var_new):`, или - зачем тут регулярные выражения? - `elif trade in card_var_new:`

Comment: Простите, я не понял немного. search - ищет, а шаблон escape что делает? Избегает?

Comment: Да, тут ЧНС. В `trade` есть скобки, а вы просто так используете эту переменную в качестве регулярного выражения. Зачем, если вы просто проверяете наличие подстроки в строке?

Comment: Я нашёл способ поиска строкой только через re. К сожалению, я так и не понял почему именно эта строка не находит

Comment: Всё, понял почему он не находил! Спасибо огромное! Сработало :)